# Blazor WASM | Web Push Notifications | iOS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, web-push

Has anyone been able to get Web Push notifications to work on iOS? I have followed the blazor pizza example https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/main/docs/09-progressive-web-app.md#sending-push-notifications and can get that to work for desktop. **Note the tutorial only has you update the service-worker.js but if you publish the app you will also need to update the service-worker.publish.js.** I am able on iOS to install the app as a PWA and it prompts me to allow notifications. I can even get a subscription:

`url - https://web.push.apple.com/QL6zHJz733--fiTROuD0EEGfsi0hhs7RUdZFXzx...p256dh - BCZ+cL6Fy1BFiBLEgJNs2dbA6YzkSYyS... auth - HJd1....`

Here is my service-worker.js

```
    console.log('Installing service worker...');
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    // You can add custom logic here for controlling whether to use cached data if offline, etc.
    // The following line opts out, so requests go directly to the network as usual.
    return null;
});

self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    const payload = event.data.json();
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification('MyApp', {
            body: payload.message,
            icon: 'icon-512.png',
            vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
            data: { url: payload.url }
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
});
```

service-worker.publish.js

```
// offline support. See https://aka.ms/blazor-offline-considerations

self.importScripts('./service-worker-assets.js');
self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(onInstall(event)));
self.addEventListener('activate', event => event.waitUntil(onActivate(event)));
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(onFetch(event)));

const cacheNamePrefix = 'offline-cache-';
const cacheName = `${cacheNamePrefix}${self.assetsManifest.version}`;
const offlineAssetsInclude = [ /\.dll$/, /\.pdb$/, /\.wasm/, /\.html/, /\.js$/, /\.json$/, /\.css$/, /\.woff$/, /\.png$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.gif$/, /\.ico$/, /\.blat$/, /\.dat$/ ];
const offlineAssetsExclude = [ /^service-worker\.js$/ ];

// Replace with your base path if you are hosting on a subfolder. Ensure there is a trailing '/'.
const base = "/";
const baseUrl = new URL(base, self.origin);
const manifestUrlList = self.assetsManifest.assets.map(asset => new URL(asset.url, baseUrl).href);

async function onInstall(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Install');

    // Fetch and cache all matching items from the assets manifest
    const assetsRequests = self.assetsManifest.assets
        .filter(asset => offlineAssetsInclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .filter(asset => !offlineAssetsExclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .map(asset => new Request(asset.url, { integrity: asset.hash, cache: 'no-cache' }));
    await caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.addAll(assetsRequests));
}

async function onActivate(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Activate');

    // Delete unused caches
    const cacheKeys = await caches.keys();
    await Promise.all(cacheKeys
        .filter(key => key.startsWith(cacheNamePrefix) && key !== cacheName)
        .map(key => caches.delete(key)));
}

async function onFetch(event) {
    let cachedResponse = null;
    if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
        // For all navigation requests, try to serve index.html from cache,
        // unless that request is for an offline resource.
        // If you need some URLs to be server-rendered, edit the following check to exclude those URLs
        const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate'
            && !manifestUrlList.some(url => url === event.request.url);

        const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);
    }

    return cachedResponse || fetch(event.request);
}

self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    const payload = event.data.json();
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification('MyApp', {
            body: payload.message,
            icon: 'icon-512.png',
            vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
            data: { url: payload.url }
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
});
```

On the server side i am using the https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp library to send the notifications

```
var pushSubscription = new PushSubscription(webPushNotification.Url, webPushNotification.P256dh, webPushNotification.Auth);
var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails("mailto:<info@example.com>", publicKey, privateKey);
var webPushClient = new WebPushClient();
try
{
    var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        message = "MyApp Notification",
        url = $"/",
    });
    await webPushClient.SendNotificationAsync(pushSubscription, payload, vapidDetails);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Error sending push notification: " + ex.Message);
}
```

I don't get an error sending the notification but it doesn't work with any subscriptions with https://web.push.apple.com/ Has anyone been able to do web push notification to https://web.push.apple.com/?

Comment: After more digging I am seeing this error when sending notifications to https://web.push.apple.com/ 

Received unexpected response code: 403. Details: {"reason":"BadJwtToken"}

But I am not getting this for notifications going to: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: Ok i found the issue. My email wasn't formatted correctly should be mail:info@example.com credit apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_web_push_notifications_in_web_apps_and_browsers

BadJwtToken
The JSON web token (JWT) has one of following issues: The JWT is missing. The JWT is signed with the wrong private key. The JWT subject claim isn’t a URL or mailto:. The JWT audience claim isn’t the origin of the push service where you sent the request. The JWT expiration parameter is more than one day into the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting response code 403 from web.push.apple.com further investigation showed that my email was not formatted correctly on the jwt `mailto:<info@example.com>` should be `mailto:info@example.com` Credit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_web_push_notifications_in_web_apps_and_browsers

> BadJwtToken The JSON web token (JWT) has one of following issues: The
> JWT is missing. The JWT is signed with the wrong private key. The JWT
> subject claim isn’t a URL or mailto:. The JWT audience claim isn’t the
> origin of the push service where you sent the request. The JWT
> expiration parameter is more than one day into the future.